# How can I compile/install VScode on ARM Linux?

Tags: python, node.js, compilation, visual-studio-code, armv7

I'm trying to compile VScode 1.2 branch from git repo.  The platform is Ubuntu trusty running in crouton on a Chomebook.  The CPU is the Nvidia Tegra K1, 32bit ARMv7.

Why can't this compile on ARM?  It looks like it's written mainly in Node.JS and Python, both of which I have on ARM, both of which are CPU agnostic.

```
=================================

philo@localhost ~/v/scripts> tail -15 npm-debug.log
6702 info installOne typechecker@2.0.8
6703 info installOne fsevents@0.3.8
6704 error notsup Unsupported
6704 error notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@0.3.8
6704 error notsup Valid OS:    darwin
6704 error notsup Valid Arch:  any
6704 error notsup Actual OS:   linux
6704 error notsup Actual Arch: arm
6705 error System Linux 3.10.18
6706 error command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
6707 error cwd /home/philo/vscode/scripts
6708 error node -v v0.10.25
6709 error npm -v 1.3.10
6710 error code EBADPLATFORM
6711 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I've edited out **fsevent** per the advice below.  I also had to `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`  However, I'm still not getting a working build:

```
npm WARN cannot run in wd code-oss-dev@1.2.1 node build/npm/postinstall.js (wd=/home/philo/vscode-release-1.2)
```

When I try to run it:

```
philo@localhost ~/vscode-release-1.2> ./scripts/code.sh 

TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign'
    at Object.create (/home/philo/vscode-release-1.2/node_modules/gulp-tsb/lib/index.js:28:16)
    at createCompile (/home/philo/vscode-release-1.2/gulpfile.js:47:15)
    at compileTask (/home/philo/vscode-release-1.2/gulpfile.js:80:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/philo/vscode-release-1.2/gulpfile.js:106:47)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)

TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign'
    at Object.create (/home/philo/vscode-release-1.2/node_modules/gulp-tsb/lib/index.js:28:16)
    at createCompile (/home/philo/vscode-release-1.2/gulpfile.js:47:15)
    at compileTask (/home/philo/vscode-release-1.2/gulpfile.js:80:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/philo/vscode-release-1.2/gulpfile.js:106:47)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
./scripts/code.sh: line 32: /home/philo/vscode-release-1.2/.build/electron/electron: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you trying to install the OS X version  (`Valid OS:    darwin`)? The valid architecture is `any`, so `arm` shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BuildingVisualStudioCodeOnARaspberryPi3.aspx)?

Comment: What version of node are you using?  Run `node -v` to output the version of node.

Comment: philo@localhost ~> nodejs -v
v0.10.25

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on CentOS 6 (x64) with:

```
./scripts/npm.sh install --arch=x64
```

It is treating this OS X specific module as a non-optional dependency. Only thing I see is that dependencies were flattened out in a [2016-04-19 commit](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/570b63910fff42ef0ee689d2e6153fbc6384392c) of **npm-shrinkwrap.json**. Not sure if that is a bug.

Since I'm not compiling for OS X, removing the **fsevent** entry from **npm-shrinkwrap.json** allowed me to continue. Internally, if **fsevent** is not present, it seems to fall back on file polling.

Comment: Thanks that helped.  I still needed to `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`.  As gyp was calling node, rather than nodejs.  I didn't see where to fix it, but the link cludge did the trick.